# Irreducible polynomial $p(x)=x^3+2x+1$

Tags: ring-theory

Consider an irreducible polynomial $p(x)=x^3+2x+1$ in the ring $\mathbb Z_3 [x]$. I beg help on  how to solve the following two cases basing the polynomial above?.

(i) Find a representative polynomial of degree less than $3$ in $\mathbb Z_3[x]/{\langle p(x)\rangle}$ to the polynomial $x^4+x\in\mathbb Z_3[x]$.

(ii) Let $\alpha=x+\langle p(x)\rangle$ in   $E=\mathbb Z_3[x]/{\langle p(x)\rangle}$. Show that $p(\alpha)=0$ in $E$.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$. If you use `<` and `>`, you get relation symbols instead, with associated bad spacing. I fixed it for you.

Comment: @ALGEAN I have never before seen quotients written the way you made them with your edit. But I have limited experience with algebraists' notation, so I am not going to override you on this.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I am quite used to algebraists' notations, and I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

(i) In $E=\mathbb Z_3/\langle p(x)\rangle$, $x^3+2x+1=0$, thus $x^3=-(2x+1)$, and $x^4=-x(2x+1)=-2x^2-x$. Thus $x^4+x=-2x^2=x^2$ since $-2=1$ in $\mathbb Z_3$.

(ii) What is $p(\alpha)$? You can compute a representative of it: 
$$p(\alpha)=p(x+\langle p(x)\rangle)=\langle (x+p(x))^3+2(x+p(x))+1\rangle=\dotsb$$
Then you just have to simplify as in (i). (Don't forget that $\langle p(x)\rangle=0$ in $E$.)